# django template get dictionary item

Tags: django, templates, dictionary

I try to work with a dictionary in my templates of django, but I can't figure out how I should access the different values of my dictionary.

My view:

```
def index(request):
    towns = Town.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    resources = []
    for town in towns:
        resources.append([town, view_resources(town)])

    print resources

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'resources': resources})
```

My view_resources returns a dictonary like this:

```
{'coin': coin, 'grain': grain, 'iron': iron, 'stone': stone, 'wood': wood,}
```

and my print gives something like:

```
[[<Town: admin's Town>, {'wood': 200, 'stone': 203, 'coin': 176, 'grain': 303, 'iron': 203}]]
```

Now my template:

```
<div>
    <table>
    {% for town, resource in resources %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>{{ town.name }}</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ resources.wood }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I access the "wood" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `resource` is the dict inside each tuple, not `resources`.

```
{{ resource.wood }}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Haha missed a damn typo :) bene stuck on that for some time haha